I have created new ASK cluster and deployed the application, but we are not receiving the SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt for the new AKS cluster
I am using manager Kubernetes cluster but when i created new AKS cluster and deployed the application on it i can see the pods are running but when i hit url in browser we are not receiving the SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt for the new AKS cluster. saying certificate is trusted.
I followed Microsoft ASK Documents to create ASK cluster but still issue is persist.
I want to access url from browser and SSL certificate error should be removed.
can anyone please suggest on this issue?
